# Annotation bug coercing string to float

Tags: python, layout, annotations, plotly, heatmap

I've encountered what I think is a bug with `create_annotated_heatmap`. I'm making a plot with annotation text with one value in the annotation that is a string but can be coerced into a float. The following should be reproducible

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
        x=['x'], 
        y=['1491', 'ab', 'cd', 'ef'], 
        z=[[1], [2], [3], [4]],
        annotation_text=[['1491'], ['ab'], ['cd'], ['ef']])
```

The output looks awful because the first y value gets passed into annotations in layout with a value of '1491' but is coerced into 1491, while the other values are treated as categories and then mapped to small integers.
[image]

I've tried assigning the heatmap to fig and running `fig.update_yaxes(type='category')` and various permutations around that. Nothing works. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to comment out the `y=[...]` and it will work. annotation_text is fine. You can check out more options if you want to have a matrix/heatmap [here](https://plotly.com/python/annotated-heatmap/). Assuming this is what you are expecting...

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
        x=['x'], ## Label on top
        #y=['1491', 'ab', 'cd', 'ef'], ##Comment out as you have just one dimension in x
        z=[[1], [2], [3], [4]], ## 4 horizontal bars, no matrix/heatmap
        annotation_text=[['1491'], ['ab'], ['cd'], ['ef']]) ## Text inside each bar
```

**Output plot**

[image]

Comment: This works great. I suppose there may still be issues in cases when there are multiple dimensions, but for me this solves my problem and makes the code cleaner.